# Calendar date selector doesn't update string when user clicks back button

Tags: jquery, forms, date, calendar

I have a calendar form on my website that allows people to select a month, day and year to look at our archives. It works fine on the first selection but when the user clicks the back button it reverts to January 1, 2012(2-1-2012). So you could first search April 1, 2014 and it will give you that date correctly. But if you click back only what you change will be updated. It will display that April is selected but it will actually return January unless you manually change the month. Same goes with the day and year.

Basically you have to manually put in the month, day and year each time even if it displays the month, day or year you want because what you see is only what you get if you choose it.

I'm using a Jason's Date Input Calendar(calendardateinput.js) This is the code.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    function testResults (form) {
    var marksstring = form;
    var myStringList = marksstring.split('-'); // split on commas
    var TestVar = 'http://www.foo.com/foo_archive/date/?operator=search&SortBy=Page&Date=' + myStringList[1] + myStringList[0] + myStringList[2];
    window.location=TestVar;
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/calendarDateInput.js"></script>

<form name="myform" action="" method="get">Choose a date to view<br>
    <script language="JavaScript">DateInput('date', false, 'DD-MM-YYYY', '02-01-2012');</script>
    <input class="img_block_center2 wider" type="button" name="button" Value="Search" onClick="testResults(this.form.date.value)">
</form>
```

Let me know if I need to clarify anything. Or I can give you think link to the actual website so you can test it yourself.

EDIT

I threw together a quick example page to show you what's going on. When you click search just refer to the URL to see what string it's returning. With our subscription model this was the easiest way I could show you what's going on. Thanks!

http://www.thebrunswicknews.com/open_access/obits_test

Comment: Same behaviour on all major browsers? Just wondering... And ya, you can provide site link in question

Comment: I added a link. And it seems to be all browsers that are affected. The day actually seems to display correctly. But the month and year are still incorrect.

Comment: Check your console, you have to fix errors prior to expect your site to work